# next step in ODE solver testing for the "Pythagorean 3-Body Proxblem"

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I ran into difficulty trying to integrate the *Pythagorean 3-Body Problem* using `scipy.odeint`. After a bit of inspection and web searching, I found the following in this very interesting integration [discussion/tutorial](http://www.simplyintegrate.de/sib/index.html#x1-40002):

> "*After a discussion of the unit scaling in the next section many different integration algorithms are described in following sections. The author recommends, after writing your own integration program according to one of these algorithms, to begin the integration exercises with the figure “eight”, since it is easy to integrate due to its stability and the fact, that close encounters do not occur at all. **Afterwards, you may try to solve the Pythagorean problem. The Pythagorean problem is difficult to integrate. A very accurate integrator must be used which is able to cope with the numerous close encounters**.*"

So my primary question is: are there other python ODE libraries I could look to, along the lines of the suggestion above? Alternatively, can someone help me understand how to coax `odeint` into working here? `scipy.odeint` has always "just worked" right out-of-the-box whenever I've used it, so I was surprised this time.

There are beautiful simulation result in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2pi5Ra-ZFQ) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rr0JpgKPKgg)

**note:** the title is not a typo - there is a bot blocking the word "problem" in the title.

I'm going to post my first try implementation below. I'd welcome comments how to write it better. By adjusting tol (and sometimes the spacing in `t` which is strange because that is interpolation, not the actual time steps for `scipy.odeint`). Once I was able to produce a correct-ish looking plot (you can see them all over the [internet](http://www.ucolick.org/~laugh/oxide/projects/burrau.html)) but I don't recall how.

[image: Wrong Answer]

```
def deriv(X, t):

    Y[:6] = X[6:]

    r34, r35, r45 = X[2:4]-X[0:2], X[4:6]-X[0:2], X[4:6]-X[2:4]
    thing34 = ((r34**2).sum())**-1.5
    thing35 = ((r35**2).sum())**-1.5
    thing45 = ((r45**2).sum())**-1.5

    Y[6:8]   =  r34*thing34*m4 + r35*thing35*m5
    Y[8:10]  =  r45*thing45*m5 - r34*thing34*m3
    Y[10:12] = -r35*thing35*m3 - r45*thing45*m4

    return Y


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint as ODEint

# Pythagorean Three Body Problem
# This script WILL NOT solve it yet, just for illustration of the problem

m3, m4, m5 = 3.0, 4.0, 5.0

x0 = [1.0, 3.0] + [-2.0, -1.0] + [1.0, -1.0]
v0 = [0.0, 0.0] + [ 0.0,  0.0] + [0.0,  0.0] 
X0 = np.array(x0 + v0)

t = np.linspace(0, 60,  50001)

Y = np.zeros_like(X0)

tol  = 1E-9 # with default method higher precision causes failure
hmax = 1E-04
answer, info = ODEint(deriv, X0, t, rtol=tol, atol=tol,
                      hmax=hmax, full_output=True)

xy3, xy4, xy5 = answer.T[:6].reshape(3,2,-1)
paths         = [xy3, xy4, xy5]

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
for x, y in paths:
    plt.plot(x, y)
for x, y in paths:
    plt.plot(x[:1], y[:1], 'ok')
plt.xlim(-6, 6)
plt.ylim(-4, 4)
plt.title("This result is WRONG!", fontsize=16)
plt.subplot(4,1,3)
for x, y in paths:
    plt.plot(t, x)
plt.ylim(-6, 4)
plt.subplot(4,1,4)
for x, y in paths:
    plt.plot(t, y)
plt.ylim(-6, 4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: For the long-term stability of the solutions you will probably need a symplectic integrator. Explicit and most implicit RK methods "leak" energy. -- Also compare solutions that vary in small amounts in the initial conditions to get a feeling for the magnification of local errors.

Comment: Those are very helpful suggestions @LutzL ! The solution these particular initial values fairly quickly decays into a binary (m=4, m=5) and m=3 by itself, but the extremely close approaches are probably throwing off the accuracy. The sensitivity analysis is an excellent suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question exactly what is going wrong with your current approach.

But, assuming the guts of your question is just : "Are there other python ODE libraries I could look to, along the lines of the suggestion above?", then you could try the other options available in `scipy.integrate.ode`. I'd try the `lsoda`, `dopri5` and `dop853` methods.

Comment: OK I'll try to update/clarify/hone the question in a few hours, and also try those... briefly I get different results (even before it stops) depending strongly on `tol`, and never seem to be able to get a stable result that looks the way it should (see the links - especially vids). This is no totally unexpected, but  [for example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748601/need-to-understand-better-how-rtol-atol-work-in-scipy-integrate-odeint) it's never happened to me before.

Comment: This is fascinating, but will take a few days, not hours. for me to put it all together.

Comment: Still working on it occasionally - [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/15369/12102) gives numerical results from a "more professional" ODE solver for these kinds of problems, so I can go back in and look at what's going wrong in more detail.